# How to generate report with detox testing?

Tags: report, e2e-testing, detox

I can able to generate HTML report using jest but can't able generate reports in end-to-end detox testing. Is there is any solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We’e had a lot of success integrating Allure Reports with our Detox regression test suites. Easy to read and works well with CICD. Just takes a little setup.
https://hughmccamphill.com/visual-regression-testing-react-native-apps-with-detox-and-jest,
https://hughmccamphill.com/adding-a-custom-reporter-to-detox